# How to output headers together with body in PHP?

Tags: php, http

There's a string like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 15 Dec 2011 12:23:25 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
Content-Length: 2039
Content-Type: text/html


<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

Is is possible to send it as headers + body with one command? I know you can use `header` and echo/print/printf to output body, but since the string I have is exactly in the form I've written, to use these functions I'd have to parse it into headers and body.

I've tried writing to `php://output`, but it seems to think headers are the body.

Comment: You should have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: @Krister Andersson — cURL is an HTTP client, as far as I know you can't use it to issue an HTTP response.

Comment: @Quentin - I was reading the "Is it possible to send it as headers + body", perhaps I misunderstood?

Comment: @Krister Andersson — The example data in the question is clearly response headers and response body not request headers and request body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you have to use `header()`. You could split the string into lines, walk the lines one by one calling `header()` for each one until you meet the empty line and then echo the rest of it.

Comment: see the output_response_string() function given below it works perfect

Answer (score 5):

There is no way (AFAIK) to write the headers to output as a raw string - PHP and the web server handle this silently in the background, to ensure the response is valid - but splitting to headers/body is easy enough:

```
function output_response_string ($responseStr) { 

  // Split the headers from the body and fetch the headers
  $parts = explode("\r\n\r\n", $responseStr);
  $headers = array_shift($parts);

  // Send headers
  foreach (explode("\r\n", $headers) as $header) {
    $header = trim($header);
    if ($header) header($header);
  }

  // Send body
  echo implode("\r\n\r\n", $parts);

}
```

As long as your response string conforms to the HTTP standard, this will work perfectly.